# URL Hacking - Custom button on Opportunity

Tags: urlhacking

I have created a custom list button on Opportunity, which takes the user's country and other details from user record and auto populates on Opportunity creation.

If I use the same custom button on Opportunity related list on Accounts, the Account is not getting auto populated on the opportunity; whereas the standard "New Opportunity" button on Opportunity related list on Account record, auto populates the Account name on Opportunity.

How do I make the custom Opportunity creation button to auto populate the Account name on Opportunity creation (when we create the opportunity from Account)

Comment: This question has been asked so many times.. A quick search should give you the answer.

Comment: Maybe rather than using these url hacks - which will break before long with new UI coming - consider using a flow to auto populate fields.